# How do I add the parameter of a javascript function into a url?

Tags: javascript

Say I have a function:

```
function potato(param) {
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(file:///C:/Users/Joe)';}
```

and I want to make it so when I call potato('/chicken.jpg'), it will modify the url in potato to be file:///C:/Users/Joe/chicken.jpg. How could this be done? Thank you

Comment: `'url(file:///C:/Users/Joe' + param + ')';`

Comment: javascript in a browser doesn't have access to the file system. Try running a local web browser with a document root of C:\User\Joe and then pass in the url path ... something like 'http://localhost/chicken.jpg'

Answer (score 0):

Javascript in a browser doesn't have access to the file system. Try running a local web browser with a document root of C:\User\Joe and then pass in the url path ... something like 'http://localhost/chicken.jpg'

Comment: No need. If he just using the page directly (using also **file** protocol) all will be ok.

Comment: As soon as the original poster publishes to a web server all will not be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Just use concatenate operator. So in JavaScript use +.

'my/base/url' + myStringVar;

'url(file:///C:/Users/Joe'+param+')';

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this. This code will replace the background image when you call the function with the param :

```
function potato(param){
  var $element = document.querySelector('.something'),
      url = 'file:///C:/Users/Joe/' + param;

  $element.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + url + "')";

  console.log('=>' + $element.style.backgroundImage);
}
```

This is live example on jsbin => https://jsbin.com/?html,console,output